# Copy a file based on date within the filename

Tags: vba, excel, filesystems

I am trying to copy a file from a shared folder to another folder. The only identifier is the previous day's date in the filename (I repeat this process every day based on date). The date format in the filename is `"yymmdd"`. We receive a new file everyday to the folder which needs to be copied, the naming convention is this `T1234567_CPyymmddS1.txt`.

I have the following code that's supposed to work, but instead it copies old files (like today it copied a file for `180117` instead of `180125`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub iSeries()
Dim myDate1 As String
Dim Ipan1 As String
Dim Ipan2 As String
Dim sFilename As String
sFilename = Dir("G:\" & Ipan2)

myDate1 = Format(Date - 1, "yymmdd")
Ipan1 = "157782_panama_iseries_" & mGlobalDate & ".txt"
Ipan2 = "*_CP*" & myDate1 & "S1.TXT*"

On Error GoTo Quit
'source path below
FileCopy "G:\" & sFilename, _
    "C:\" & mFilePath & "\" & Ipan1
Quit:
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `mGlobalDate` declared? Where is `Ipan2` used after being initialised?

Comment: `SFilename` is being built ***before*** `Ipan2`?? Which suggests the only reason ***anything*** is being copied is due to the second `*` in `"*_CP*"`

Comment: mGlobalDate is declared as a Global Variable in another module, I forgot to edit that out. You guys are right the sFilename coming before Ipan2 was the issue, don't know how I couldn't figure that out... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building `SFilename` before you've put anything in `Ipan2`. Also, you don't need to error trap like that. If the file doesn't exist then `SFilename` will be empty so just test for that.

Try:

```
Sub iSeries()
    Dim myDate1 As String
    Dim Ipan1 As String
    Dim Ipan2 As String
    Dim sFilename As String

    myDate1 = Format(Date - 1, "yymmdd")
    Ipan1 = "157782_panama_iseries_" & mGlobalDate & ".txt"
    Ipan2 = "*_CP" & myDate1 & "S1.TXT*"    ' second * removed
    sFilename = Dir("G:\" & Ipan2)

    Debug.Print "Ipan2 (search criteria) : " & Ipan2

    If sFilename = "" Then
        MsgBox "File not found"
    Else
        Debug.Print "sFilename (match found) : " & sFilename 
        'source path below
        FileCopy "G:\" & sFilename, _
        "C:\" & mFilePath & "\" & Ipan1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry tested the code again putting sFilename after Ipan2 and it still does the same thing, it doesn't copy the file with the correct date, instead it copies the first file in the folder.

Comment: I've added a couple of `Debug.Print` lines to aid you in finding what's failing here.

Comment: Came in to work this morning, ran the macro and oddly enough it seems to be working now, I don't understand why at all. I'll mark this as answered, and I guess I'll comment if it "breaks again". Thanks for the help either way!

Answer (score 1):

The statement sFilename = Dir("G:\" & Ipan2) should come after the Ipan2 = "*_CP*" & myDate1 & "S1.TXT*" statement